# resize the width of the div based on sibling div availability

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 divs on a same row. When the div2 which is on right is removed I want the div1 on left to take full width.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavender;">Div1/div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">Div2</div>
  </div>
```

I am using bootstrap for grid and resposivity. Is there any way I could achieve it with bootstrap?

Comment: what do you mean by 'removed'? As a result of user's click or what.. ?

Comment: Yeah. When user clicks

Answer (score 2):

You could write a css selector that sets the width of col-sm-6 to be 100% it is both the first-child and last-child

```
.row .col-sm-6:first-child:last-child {
    width:100%
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bootstrap4, then you can skip the column size declaration and instead just do.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm" style="background-color:lavender;">Div1/div>
    <div class="col-sm" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">Div2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: To back this answer, here is a link to bootstrap's 4 doc that explain this:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#equal-width

Comment: @Sylvain : thank you. I think bootstrap4 has the flex system and grid combined.